# SSRS Report - Column auto generated in date range by weekly

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying make a SSRS report that can automatic count monthly in date range.

I'm using SQL 2012 and VS 2010

Below is SQL that i'm using, for example:

SELECT p.YearGroup
,count(p1.PupilID) as Aug13
,count(p2.PupilID) as Sep13
,count(p3.PupilID) as Oct13
,count(p4.PupilID) as Nov13
,count(p5.PupilID) as Dec13
,count(p6.PupilID) as Jan14
,count(p7.PupilID) as Feb14
FROM Pupils AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pupils AS p1 on p.PupilID=p1.PupilID and p1.StartDate between '2013-08-01 00:00:00' and '2013-09-01 00:00:00'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pupils AS p2 on p.PupilID=p2.PupilID and p2.StartDate between '2013-09-01 00:00:00' and '2013-10-01 00:00:00'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pupils AS p3 on p.PupilID=p3.PupilID and p3.StartDate between '2013-10-01 00:00:00' and '2013-11-01 00:00:00'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pupils AS p4 on p.PupilID=p4.PupilID and p4.StartDate between '2013-11-01 00:00:00' and '2013-12-01 00:00:00'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pupils AS p5 on p.PupilID=p5.PupilID and p5.StartDate between '2013-12-01 00:00:00' and '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pupils AS p6 on p.PupilID=p6.PupilID and p6.StartDate between '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2014-02-01 00:00:00'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Pupils AS p7 on p.PupilID=p7.PupilID and p7.StartDate between '2014-02-01 00:00:00' and '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY p.YearGroup

The result should be like this:
YearGroup | Aug13 | Sep13| Oct13 | ...
   1      |   55  |  56  |   56  | ...
   2      |   43  |  42  |   44  | ...
...

Please help

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is getting your fields into your dataset (Year, YearMonth, Day, etc...). Then simply add a matrix or a tablix to your report and drag and drop your fields into it. I am not sure how your arrangement should be, based on your example but just try a little and you will find the right order soon.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to use a query which allow date time will be generated automatically. My query just created manual by using Self Join. Any ideas?